# How to slice a 3d numpy array into 2d using height from another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays:

```py
a.shape
# (1024, 768, 100)
heights.shape
# (1024, 768)
```

I would like to extract a 2-dimensional image from `a` which would take a single element along the axis `2`, taking its index from `heights`. Something like this:

```py
result = a[:,:,h]
```

where `h` is a value (in appropriate coordinates) in array `heights`.

Result would have shape `(1024, 768)`.

Using the loops it would be easy, but inefficient:

```py
result = np.zeros(heights.shape)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        h = heights[i][j]
        result[i][j] = a[i][j][h]
```

Example:

```py
a = np.arange(30).reshape((3,2,5)) + 5
# array([[[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#         [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],
#
#        [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#         [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],
#
#        [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
#         [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]]])

heights = np.asarray([[0, 2], [1, 4], [1, 3]])
# array([[0, 2],
#        [1, 4],
#        [1, 3]])

print(expected_result)
# array([[ 5, 12],
#        [16, 24],
#        [26, 33]]
```

How can I do this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With combination of [`numpy.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) + [`numpy.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(a, heights[:, :, None], -1))
```

---

```
array([[ 5, 12],
       [16, 24],
       [26, 33]])
```

Answer (score 2):

A more manual solution, you can create the proper [fancy index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) using broadcasting:

```
a[np.arange(h.shape[0])[:, None], np.arange(h.shape[1]), h]
```